# How to detect the maximum current for this waveform?

Tags: voltage, current, esd, tvs

I need to select a TVS diode for ethernet applications and came across this [application note](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slvae37/slvae37.pdf?ts=1669964879611&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F). I want to find the right clamping peak current and the clamping voltage of the TVS diode.

Here, on page 4, section 2.3, they mention that the current rating for the tvs diode should be chosen according to the waveform?

And they mention, the 10/1000 μs waveform as defined in IEC61643-123 or the IEC 61000-4-5 8/20 μs waveform. Can someone tell me which is the waveform standard that I should refer for the ethernet application and how to find the maximum current from the waveform?

Also, if my application is for USB, would it be the same waveform?

Comment: The waveform is not related whether the interface you want to protect is USB or Ethernet. It's about the waveform of the overvoltage event you want to handle.

Comment: What is the threat you need to protect against? This always has to be defined first.

Comment: I'd want to protect for ESD events. In that case?

Comment: Then you wouldn't use either of those standards <-- they are indirect lightning surge standards. If you want to protect against ESD, what area or component on your circuit is the likely victim?

Comment: The ethernet magnetics/transformer and the PHY device

Comment: PHY will be protected by the magnetics and, the magnetics is robust enough.

Comment: Then could you please tell me how to chose the ESD diode current and voltage rating ? @Andyaka

Comment: It always come down to the spec you are trying to meet, the voltage discharge rating in that spec and, what you are trying to protect. In short, the threat and the victim

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141046/discussion-between-newbie-and-andy-aka).